# Websphere Application Server 6.1 TE installation issue with RAD 8.0

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, websphere-6.1, ibm-rad

I installed RAD 8.0 on my desktop and WAS 7.0 already..
now i want to install WAS 6.1 in my desktop. When i tried to install that it gives an error like below:

```
IBM WAS 6.1(64 bit) Test Environment 6.1.0.41 cannot be installed into any package group.
CRIMA1071E: The installation package 'IBM® WebSphere® Application Server V6.1 (64-bit) Test Environment' requires components supplied by other packages.
The required components might be supplied by the specified features of the following installation packages:
Package: Rational Application Developer 8.0 -- Features: WebSphere® Application Server, version 6.1 development tools
Package: The following packages cannot be installed into the same package group: IBM WebSphere Application Server Version 6.1 (32-bit) Test Environment IBM WebSphere Application Server Version 6.1 (64-bit) Test Environment.
```

Answer (score 0):

As the message says you should also install **WebSphere® Application Server, version 6.1 development tools Package** in RAD in order to use WAS 6.1 Test Environment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing WAS 6.1(64 bit) to a new `package group`? It seems that it cannot coexist with 32 bit version as your error message states that

```
Package: The following packages cannot be installed into the same package group: IBM WebSphere Application Server Version 6.1 (32-bit) Test Environment IBM WebSphere Application Server Version 6.1 (64-bit) Test Environment.
```

It seems that you're either selecting both versions (32 and 64-bit) during package selection, which cannot coexist in same package group, or your package group already contains 32-bit version.

Quoting [Package groups and the shared resources directory](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/install/v1m0r0/topic/com.ibm.cic.agent.ui.doc/topics/c_install_location.html), it seems that you shall choose to use a new package group during installation;

> You install packages into a package group. A package group represents
>   a directory in which packages share resources with other packages in
>   the same group. When you install packages with Installation Manager,
>   you can choose to create a new package group or install the packages
>   into an existing package group. (Some packages might not be able to
>   share a package group, in which case the option to use an existing
>   package group will be disabled.)